# Unresolved reference async/await in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Sometimes in PyCharm 2017.1.4 with python3.6 `async/await` statements show as unresolved, although there aren't any errors and in next tab `async/await` not underlined as an error.

Restarting fix this issue.
How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: What's your *question*? If you think there's a problem with PyCharm, raise it with JetBrains.

Comment: This happened to me because of an unclosed statement above my function (missing close-paren)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just hit the same problem. It was because the project interpreter was set to python2.7, the await/async keys are new as of python3, and not backward compatible.

preferences>project>project-interpreter is where I could select the correction version.

Comment: Project interpreter set python3.6. That is a bug of Pycharm

Comment: Interpreter set to 2.5, encountered same bug, PyCharm 2017.3.3

Comment: Interpreter set to 3.7, encountered same bug, PyCharm 2019.1.1

Comment: Is this still a bug?

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same issue since I erroneously used the 'await' outside of an async method (Interpreter set to Python 3.6).
'await' is only valid in an 'async' method using Python 3.6. Pycharm correctly produces the error, but the message 'await unresolved' is not specific.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2022.1.2 this still seems to happen.
If you are not using `await` outside of `async` method, your interpreter is setup correctly, etc. and the code is working fine, you can just surpress the warning:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
await ...
```